# Java popup, Jpanel and PopupFactory - update x and y coordinates

Tags: java, swing

I have a Jpanel, which I want to add a info popup on right click.  So, the coordinates of the popup can change.  However, when I add a popup in the paintComponent method, the application slows down considerably.

I am using the following code to get an instance of the popup from the popupFactory in the paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

if(Show){
    popup = factory.getPopup(this, l, mouseX, mouseY); 
    popup.show();
}
```

l is a simple JLabel.
Is there another way to add an info popup on right click on a Jpanel.

Cheers,

Slotishtype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another way to add an info popup on right click on a Jpanel.

The normal way is to use a MouseListener and to listen for the right mouse click and then display the popup. The paintComponent() method has nothing to do with displaying popups, since the popup is not part of the component.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be adding a popup every time the component is painted.

Comment: I know.  But the popupFactory does not allow me to update the coordinates of the popup....It there another way around this?

Comment: In getPopup()  you are passing the coordinates in.  Assuming you are using a mouseListener, each right click could have difference coords, I don't understand the issue you are having?

Comment: Even if I set the coordinates as static so: popup = factory.getPopup(this, l, 189, 123); : the application slows down because paintComponenet is being called at a frame rate of 60X per second.  If I add the popup in the contstructor, there is no  problem but then I am unable to change the coordinates using the mouseListener....

Comment: Don't use static coordinates.  Just use the mouse listener and whenever you get a new click create a new popup, just like you were doing in the paint component.   A SCCEE would be nice.

Comment: I know but the application starts to crawl once I add a popup...But surely, it must be a common use of the popup - to add it to a paintable component?

Comment: No it is not a common use or recommend to add popup code to the painting methods.